# Docker registry can't bind to hostIP:5000

Tags: docker, registry, push

I'm trying to push an image to a docker registry that I'm running as a container on another machine. I start the registry by mounting the config.yml in an external volume. The default value for the http: addr field in this file is "localhost:5000". That works but I can't push from the other machine. I get the error:

> "unable to connect to 192.168.1.149:5000. Do you need an HTTP proxy?"

But these are all machines on a local network, so there should be no proxy needed.
When I set this value to the ip address of the machine: 192.168.1.149:5000, I get the error:

> "level=fatal msg="listen tcp 192.168.1.149:5000: bind: cannot assign
> requested address"

My config file looks like this:

```
version: 0.1
log:
  accesslog:
    disabled: true
  level: debug
  formatter: text
  fields:
    service: registry
    environment: development
loglevel: debug # deprecated: use "log"
storage:
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
    maxthreads: 100
  delete:
    enabled: false
  redirect:
    disable: false
http:
  addr: localhost:5000
  tls:
    certificate: /etc/docker/registry/server-cert.pem
    key: /etc/docker/registry/server-key.pem
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
  http2:
    disabled: false
```

I launch the container like this:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry -v /etc/docker/registry:/etc/docker/registry  -v `pwd`/config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml registry:2
```

And my push looks like this:

```
docker push 192.168.1.149:5000/ironclads-api:1.5
```

I can ping 192.168.1.149 from the machine I'm trying to push from and I configured the certs according to the docker instructions. Any ideas what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's running in a container, and listening on localhost inside that container, which is a different network namespace from your host (and so a different localhost), it's only reachable from inside that container. Instead, don't listen on localhost or the host IP, listen on all interfaces inside the contianer. The port forward is used to direct traffic from the host into the container.

The fix is to remove localhost, and replace it with nothing, or 0.0.0.0 if you want to bind on all IPv4 interfaces.

```yaml
http:
  addr: ":5000"
```

Comment: Thanks @BMitch. That seems to work. I don't get an error when I push, but I do get the message "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority". I'm having trouble confirming the the image was actually pushed. When I try to do a docker pull of that image on the remote registry, it comes back with an x509 error response.